# How to get key and value from SOAP Webservice?

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

i am try to using **ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

i have try to get Key and value, but i can't..
i have try this code.

```
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                SOAP_ADDRESS_URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive response1 = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            String strRes = response1.toString();
            Log.i("test", "callGetUserByUserName::->" + strRes);

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception q) {
            q.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i got response from webservice this and i can see this is log.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <NewDataSet>
      <Table>
        <MobileAppUserID>17</MobileAppUserID>
        <UserName>testmit88@gmail.com</UserName>
        <Password>testmit88</Password>
        <Firstname>testmit</Firstname>
        <Lastname>testmit</Lastname>
        <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
        <ResetPW>false</ResetPW>
      </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
```

Comment: http://www.wsdl2code.com/Pages/Example.aspx try this code generator it will help you getting parser code in java with all key value items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are geting the response then do this after getting the response..

```
public **YOUR_RETURN_TYPE** parseObject(SoapObject soapObject)  throws SocketException,SocketTimeoutException,IOException{
        SoapObject _temp = soapObject;

        SoapObject diffgramObject = (SoapObject) _temp.getProperty("diffgram");     
        SoapObject newDataSetObject = (SoapObject) diffgramObject
                .getProperty("NewDataSet");

        if(diffgramObject.hasProperty("NewDataSet"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newDataSetObject.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                CategoryBean categoryBean = new CategoryBean();

                SoapObject tableObject = (SoapObject) newDataSetObject
                        .getProperty(i);
                SoapPrimitive catId = (SoapPrimitive) tableObject
                        .getProperty("MobileAppUserID");
                categoryBean.setCatId(Integer.valueOf(catId.toString()));
                SoapPrimitive propertyId = (SoapPrimitive) tableObject
                        .getProperty("UserName");
                categoryBean.setPropertyId(Integer.valueOf(propertyId.toString()));         
                SoapPrimitive categoryName = (SoapPrimitive) tableObject
                        .getProperty("Password");
                categoryBean.setCategoryName(categoryName.toString());

                ...........

                //SET DATA TO YOUR COLLECTION OBJECT

            }
            return YOUR_COLLECTION_OBJECT;
        }

    }
```

Comment: plz check this. if you have any problem then let me know

Comment: Thanks for reply, do you please tell me what is  "diffgram" in SoapObject diffgramObject = (SoapObject) _temp.getProperty("diffgram");

Comment: hit the url in web browser and check which object you are getting. I get the diffgram for my response. it may be same in your case also

Comment: 09-02 11:46:36.992: W/System.err(3128): java.lang.RuntimeException: illegal property: NewDataSet

Comment: replace getProperty() by getAttribute() and check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60431/discussion-between-narendra-pal-and-amit-prajapati).